# Can I check a property on a generic object by passing in a lambda expression to get the parameter?

Tags: c#, linq

Simple example, I have a `Cat` object with a `Name` property.

I have a class with a method called `PrintName<T>(T objectToPrint)`

I can't do `Console.WriteLine(objectToPrint.Name)` because it's type `T`.

So can I pass in the parameter as a linq expression that gets the name? Something like;

```
Cat c = new Cat("Bernard the Cat");

PrintName(cat, parameter: c => c.Name);
```

Then PrintName can just do

`Console.WriteLine(cat.RunLinq(parameter));`

Comment: You can introduce interface `IName` which contains definition for property Name and write `PrintName<T>(T objectToPrint) where T:IName`. Then you can write `objectToPrint.Name`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider that if there is no way to do it without using an interface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you could use an Interface, but if the property can change, you could do.

**First solution : if you need the property's name**

```
PrintName<T>(T objectToPrint, Expression<Func<T, object>> property)
```

usage

```
PrintName(cat, c=> c.Name)
```

Then to get the "name" of the property, something like that.

```
var name = (property.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name
```

**Second solution : if you need the property's value**

if you want the value of the property, use a `Func<T, object> func` parameter

```
// object if you don't know the type of the property, 
// you can limit it to string if needed, of course
PrintName<T>(T objectToPrint, Func<T, object> func)
```

usage

```
PrintName(cat, c => c.Name)
```

then

```
var value = func(cat)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you need the `property.Body as MemberExpression...` line, can you explain? The other answer just uses `parameter(cat)` which seems simpler and to make more sense. I'd like to understand the theory behind your answer though.

Comment: I was not sure to understand, that's why I gave you the 2 solutions : first (before edit) gives you the property's name, second (after edit) the property's value. Choose which one you need.

Answer (score 3):

The way this is usually done is to pass the type of `cat` through using generics:

```
void PrintName<T>(T cat, Func<T, string> parameter) {
 Console.WriteLine(parameter(cat));
}
```

The delegate can use the exact type of `T` and therefore access `Name`. LINQ works that way a lot (`OrderBy`, ...). If we replaced `T` by `object` this pattern would not work because the type would not be passed through.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an interface and implement it at the each object that should support printing

```
interface IPrintable
{
  string Name{get;}
}

class Cat : IPrintable
{
  string Name{get{retrun "Dog";}}
}

void PrintName(IPrintable objectToPrint)
{
  Console.WriteLine(objectToPrint.Name);
}

var cat = new Cat();
PrintName(cat);
```

You can use reflection or dynamic to implement it without interface implementation

```
void PrintName<T>(T objectToPrint)
{
  dynamic o = (dynamic)objectToPrint;
  Console.Writeline(o.Name);
}
```